# Java Swing: popup : display small icon in menu

Tags: java, swing, menu, icons

I have a right click popup menu that works fine.

I now want to add a little image next to the text.

I managed to display the image in the popupmenu but its the full size version.

what I want to know is:

is there a way to automatically reize the icon to be the right size ( same as the text ) or do I have to resize the image?

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to resize the Icon to be whatever size you want it to be. Something like:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( ... );
Image image = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( image ) );
```

Comment: sorry to bother you could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297003/swing-resize-image-but-keep-same-size I have a feeling you might know this too lol