# Swing: resize Image but keep same size

Tags: java, image, swing, scaling

I want to be able to do something similar to resize canvas in gimp

I want to generate a bunch of images to a certain width.

I used

```
int width = (int)(size * fraction);
int height =(int)(size*icon.getIconHeight()/icon.getIconWidth()*fraction);
miniature = new ImageIcon(i.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

this goes well while I'm doing fraction 1 but I have 3 images that have the same source but are different size (1, 2/3, 1/3)

the problem is

I have and image A
I want to create B, C and D such as the drawing inside respect the follow ratio
B = A
C = 2/3 A
D = 1/3 A

but the image stays the same dimension A = B = C = D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm following what you are trying to do...

Create a JLabel for each image:

```
JLable l = new JLabel(miniture);
```

Create a JLabel with a GridLayout:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
```

Add the labels to the panel:

```
p.add(l);
```

The GridLayout will ensure that all the JLabels will have the same height and width.