# Custom Icons on JTree

Tags: java, swing, icons

I have two questions for Icons.

I am using ImageIcons as default Icons on JTree. As suggested by tutorials I am loading icons using this method :

```
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {

        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
}
```

Although in order for this to work I have to store the images inside the file with the source code which I believe is messy (but I read its needed for running on .jar). Is there a way to load images similarly while they are on the project folder and not on src ?

Also is there a way to automatically scale images on the correct size for displaying on JTree? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code doesn't load the ImageIcon from the `src` folder. It loads it from the runtime classpath. And for the images to be in the runtime classpath, the easiest way is indeed to place them in the `src` folder, so that your IDE automatically copies them to the target folder, along with the .class files.

If you want, you may define another source directory (named `resources`, for example) in your project, and the IDE will also copy the files of this source directory to the target folder. This allows separating Java files from resource files.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If it's Eclipse: right-click - New source folder.

Comment: I found how to define another source directory but how I reference it from the classes of the other src?

Comment: The same way as you did before. Eclipse compiles the two sources directory to the same target directory. Everything is in the classpath at runtime. Java doesn't care about how your sources are organized. It just loads classes and resources from the classpath. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: Yes I already tried that thats why I'm asking. Images/JTreeIcons/java.png - resources/Images/JTreeIcons/java.png -/resources/Images/JTreeIcons/java.png . I guess ill try a bit more.

Comment: Try something like `"/resources/the.png"`.  The initial `/` says the image can be found from the root of the class-path, which will get around any complications caused by calling the code from within a class in a package.

Comment: turned out i didn't need the /resources. Should have tried earlier. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to load images similarly while they are on the project folder and not on src ?

Yes, you can use the `String` constructor for `ImageIcon`, which lets you specify a file path:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("images/image.png")
```

You can use a path relative to the working directory, or an absolute path.

> Also is there a way to automatically scale images on the correct size for displaying on JTree?

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295195/java-swing-popup-display-small-icon-in-menu), I think that would let you do what you want.

Comment: Thanks ! Just had to find default icon size which is 16*16